# Sending file using multipart/form-data and SpringBoot on backend

Tags: spring, vue.js, axios, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send file from vue.js using axios and receive it in spring-based backend. 
Here's my frontend part:

```
uploadMap(context, map){

      console.log('uploading map...')
      const formData = new FormData();

      formData.append("file", map);

      axios.post("/info/map/upload", formData)
          .then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
          }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
    },
```

and on backend:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, value = "/info/uploadFile")
    public void uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("file uploaded");

        String basePath = "/Users/admin/software/app1/uploads/";

        String filePath = basePath + file.getOriginalFilename();
        File dest = new File(filePath);
        file.transferTo(dest);
    }
```

Backend part works when using Insomnia/Postman for testing. But when I want to invoke my frontend code, I get on backned:

```
2020-02-23 17:38:52.038  WARN 61799 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary2cAmVUpGnPfkQax3' not supported]
```

How should I deal with that? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Front end uses path `/info/map/upload`, while method of controller has different mapping. Is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency to your Maven config:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then register new bean with special name:

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    return multipartResolver;
}
```